# Why does capturing stateless lambdas sometimes results in increased size?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, memory-optimization

Given a chain of lambdas where each one captures the previous one by value:

```
auto l1 = [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n'; };
auto l2 = [=](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << '-' << b << '\n'; l1(a, b); };
auto l3 = [=](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << '#' << b << '\n'; l2(a, b); };
auto l4 = [=](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << '%' << b << '\n'; l3(a, b); };

std::cout << sizeof(l4);
```

We can observe, that the resulting [`sizeof` of `l4` is equal to `1`](https://godbolt.org/z/oEM6f6873).

That makes sense to me. We are capturing lambdas by value and each of those objects has to have `sizeof` equal to `1`, but since they are stateless, an optimization similar to `[[no_unique_address]]` one applies (especially since they all have unique types).

However, when I try to create a generic builder for chaining comparators, [this optimization no longer takes place](https://godbolt.org/z/54T4994cT):

```
template <typename Comparator>
auto comparing_by(Comparator&& comparator) {
    return comparator;
}

template <typename Comparator, typename... Comparators>
auto comparing_by(Comparator&& comparator, Comparators&&... remaining_comparators) {
    return [=](auto left, auto right) {
        auto const less = comparator(left, right);
        auto const greater = comparator(right, left);
        if (!less && !greater) {
            return comparing_by(remaining_comparators...)(left, right);
        }
        return less;
    };
}

struct triple {
    int x, y, z;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto by_x = [](triple left, triple right) { return left.x < right.x; };
    auto by_y = [](triple left, triple right) { return left.y < right.y; };
    auto by_z = [](triple left, triple right) { return left.z < right.z; };

    auto comparator = comparing_by(by_x, by_z, by_y);

    std::cout << sizeof(comparator);
}
```

*Note 1: I am aware of the fact that `comparing_by` is inefficient and sometimes calls the comparator in a redundant fashion.*

Why in the above case the resulting `sizeof` of `comparator` is equal to `3` and not to `1`? It is still stateless, after all. Where am I wrong? Or is it just a missed optimization in all of the big three compilers?

*Note 2: This is purely an academic question. I am not trying to solve any particular problem.*

Comment: Why do you need the size of the (very implementation-specific) lambda object? What is the actual underlying problem that knowledge would solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not trying to solve any particular problem. I am just interested whether it is a missed optimization or there is something in the language that prevents it from being applied. Althought I admit that I should've probably included the [tag:language-lawyer] tag from the beginning to indicate that this is purely academic question.

Comment: I am not sure that the _language-lawyer_ tag makes sense here. You are asking about implementation issues.

Comment: @DanielLangr but those would be actual implementation issues **only** if the standard doesn't mandate that in such cases no such optimization may take place. Am I correct?

Comment: Then please state, in the question itself, that this is just for curiosity. Otherwise people will continue to ask for a possible underlying problem and think this is an XY problem.

Comment: the lambda returned by `compare_by` does not capture one lambda that captures one ... but it has to capture all of them

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ocrrdPqsW), the answer is quite obvious: `comparator` is not suitable for empty base optimization.

Comment: Possibly simplified demo: https://godbolt.org/z/eT3a4E99v. Note that the lambda in `f3` needs to capture all three lambdas `l1`, `l2`, and `l3`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that is the thing I oversaw, I believe. @康桓瑋 suggested a reduced example. That makes sense to me. Thanks to @DanielLangr for providing yet another reduced example. I am not sure what to do with this question now. If anyone is up for formulating an answer explaining what are the internal processes and possible inabilities to introduce `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute here (I assume it has something to do with overlapping subobjects), I would be greateful. A flag for duplicate regarding the same thing would also work.

Comment: It might be worth asking another simpler question, that is, whether implementations are allowed to apply the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute for lambda member variables. Demo comparing both options: https://godbolt.org/z/5ceMqe77s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening in the first example is not what you think it is. Let's say `l1` has type `L1`, `l2` `L2`
, etc. These are the members of those types:

```cpp
struct L1 {
   // empty;
};

sizeof(L1) == 1

struct L2 {
    L1 l1;
};

sizeof(L2) == sizeof(L1)  // 1

struct L3 {
    L2 l2;
};

sizeof(L3) == sizeof(L2)  // 1

struct L4 {
    L3 l3;
};

sizeof(L4) == sizeof(L3)  // 1
```

And in your next example, you capture all the lambdas by value, so the closure type has three non-overlapping members, so the size will be at least 3.

`[[no_unique_address]]` can't be generically applied to the data members of a closure type (consider a empty class that puts its address in a global map).

The compiler could use empty base optimisation for a "well behaved type" (a trivilly-copyable empty type maybe?), so this might be a missed optimisation. The standard says this about what can be done ([expr.prim.lambda.closure]p2):

> The closure type is not an aggregate type.
> An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:
>
> - the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable ([class.prop]), or
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class ([class.prop]).

So the change in size is OK, but it would have to be done so that `is_empty_v<lambda_that_captures_stateless_lambda>` is not `true` (since that's an observable behaviour)

---

To "manually" apply this optimisation, you can, instead of calling the lambda `comparator(left, right)`, default construct something of the type of the closure type and call that (`decltype(comparator){}(left, right)`). I've implemented that here: https://godbolt.org/z/73M1Gd3o5